# Recursively form multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

Below is my rough attempt at forming a multidimensional array using only loops. Needless to say that this is a very poor example and the repetition of codes is obvious.

My question is, how can I achieve the same result using recursion in PHP?

**Example Inputs**

```
$tree = array (   
    315241 =>    array (     
        7877 =>      array (     ),
        3238 =>      array (     ),
        584 =>      array (     ),
        110 =>      array (     ),
        155 =>      array (     ),
        148 =>      array (     ),
        3052 =>      array (     ),
        313045 =>      array (     ),
        3460 =>      array (     ),
        311203 =>      array (     ),
        308 =>      array (     ),
        8152 =>      array (     ),
        115051 =>      array (     ),
        92540 =>      array (     ),
        156 =>      array (     ),
        21846 =>      array (     ),
        99885 =>      array (     ),
        315581 =>      array (     ),
        315394 =>      array (     ),
        3828 =>      array (     ),
        4949 =>      array (     ),
        847 =>      array (     ),
        315802 =>      array (     ),
        6234 =>      array (     ),
        8882 =>      array (     ),
        1 =>      array (     ),
   ), 
)

$users = {
"7877":315241,
"3238":315241,
"584":315241,
"312971":3238,
"313770":3238,
"315329":313770,
"313771":313770,
"315395":313771,
"129314":584,
"62620":584,
"88754":62620,
"183259":88754,
"121897":88754,
"315345":121897,
}

foreach($tree["top"] as $upline1 => $value){
    foreach($users as $downline => $upline){
        if($upline == $upline1){
            $tree["top"][$upline][$downline] = [] ;
            unset($users[$downline]); 
        }
    }
    $level++;
    foreach($tree["top"][$upline1] as $upline2 => $value){
        foreach($users as $downline => $upline){
            if($upline == $upline2){
                $tree["top"][$upline1][$upline][$downline] = [] ;
                unset($users[$downline]); 
            }
        }
        $level++;
        foreach($tree["top"][$upline1][$upline2] as $upline3 => $value){
            foreach($users as $downline => $upline){
                if($upline == $upline3){
                    $tree["top"][$upline1][$upline2][$upline][$downline] = [] ;
                    unset($users[$downline]); 
                }
            }
            $level++;
            foreach($tree["top"][$upline1][$upline2][$upline3] as $upline4 => $value){
                foreach($users as $downline => $upline){
                    if($upline == $upline4){
                        $tree["top"][$upline1][$upline2][$upline3][$upline][$downline] = [] ;
                        unset($users[$downline]); 
                    }
                }
                $level++;
                foreach($tree["top"][$upline1][$upline2][$upline3][$upline4] as $upline5 => $value){
                    foreach($users as $downline => $upline){
                        if($upline == $upline5){
                            $tree["top"][$upline1][$upline2][$upline3][$upline4][$upline][$downline] = [] ;
                            unset($users[$downline]); 
                        }
                    }
                    $level++;
                    foreach($tree["top"][$upline1][$upline2][$upline3][$upline4][$upline5] as $upline6 => $value){
                        foreach($users as $downline => $upline){
                            if($upline == $upline6){
                                $tree["top"][$upline1][$upline2][$upline3][$upline4][$upline5][$upline][$downline] = [] ;
                                unset($users[$downline]); 
                            }
                        }
                        $level++;
                        foreach($tree["top"][$upline1][$upline2][$upline3][$upline4][$upline5][$upline6] as $upline7 => $value){
                            foreach($users as $downline => $upline){
                                if($upline == $upline7){
                                    $tree["top"][$upline1][$upline2][$upline3][$upline4][$upline5][$upline6][$upline][$downline] = [] ;
                                    unset($users[$downline]); 
                                }
                            }
                            $level++;
                            foreach($tree["top"][$upline1][$upline2][$upline3][$upline4][$upline5][$upline6][$upline7] as $upline8 => $value){
                                foreach($users as $downline => $upline){
                                    if($upline == $upline8){
                                        $tree["top"][$upline1][$upline2][$upline3][$upline4][$upline5][$upline6][$upline7][$upline][$downline] = [] ;
                                        unset($users[$downline]); 
                                    }
                                }
                                $level++;
                                foreach($tree["top"][$upline1][$upline2][$upline3][$upline4][$upline5][$upline6][$upline7][$upline8] as $upline9 => $value){
                                    foreach($users as $downline => $upline){
                                        if($upline == $upline9){
                                            $tree["top"][$upline1][$upline2][$upline3][$upline4][$upline5][$upline6][$upline7][$upline8][$upline][$downline] = [] ;
                                            unset($users[$downline]); 
                                        }
                                    }
                                    $level++;
                                    foreach($tree["top"][$upline1][$upline2][$upline3][$upline4][$upline5][$upline6][$upline7][$upline8][$upline9] as $upline10 => $value){
                                        foreach($users as $downline => $upline){
                                            if($upline == $upline10){
                                                $tree["top"][$upline1][$upline2][$upline3][$upline4][$upline5][$upline6][$upline7][$upline8][$upline9][$upline][$downline] = [] ;
                                                unset($users[$downline]); 
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EXPECTED** example result:

```
315241 =>    array (     
        7877 =>     [],
        3238 =>      array (       
            312971 =>        [],
            313770 =>        array (         
                315329 =>          [],
                313771 =>          array (           
                    315395 =>            [],         
                ),
            ),       
        ),     
        584 =>      array (       
            62620 =>        array (         
                88754 =>          array (           
                    183259 =>            [],
                    121897 =>            array (             
                        315345 =>              [],
                    ),    
                ),
            ),       
            129314 =>        [],
        ), 
   ),
```

Here is my attempt at doing it the recursive way. However, the result is different from the above code.

```
private function recursive($tree,$users,$uplineID){
    if(!empty($users)){
        foreach($tree[$uplineID] as $uplineA => $value){
            foreach($users as $downline => $upline){
                if($upline == $uplineA){
                    $tree[$uplineID][$uplineA][] = $downline ;
                    unset($users[$downline]); 
                }else{
                    $tree[$uplineID][$uplineA] = [];
                }
            }
            $tree = $this->recursive($tree[$uplineID],$users,$uplineA);
        }
    }else{
        return $tree;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
array (   315241 =>    
    array (     
        7877 =>      array (     ),
        3238 =>      array (     ),
        584 =>      array (     ),
        110 =>      array (     ),
        155 =>      array (     ),
        148 =>      array (     ),
        3052 =>      array (     ),
        313045 =>      array (     ),
        3460 =>      array (     ),
        311203 =>      array (     ),
        308 =>      array (     ),
        8152 =>      array (     ),
        115051 =>      array (     ),
        92540 =>      array (     ),
        156 =>      array (     ),
        21846 =>      array (     ),
        99885 =>      array (     ),
        315581 =>      array (     ),
        315394 =>      array (     ),
        3828 =>      array (     ),
        4949 =>      array (     ),
        847 =>      array (     ),
        315802 =>      array (     ),
        6234 =>      array (     ),
        8882 =>      array (     ),
        1 =>      array (     ),
    ), 
)
```

Comment: What does your input data look like? Should the output look like the first example?

Comment: @PeterRakmanyi i have updated the question with input

Comment: It would be best if you gave us the current and expected results using the sample input data that you provide in the question. (not a chunk of the 1k+ lines from a different sample set)

Comment: @mickmackusa i have updated the question, that's my expected result

Comment: `320` is in `$users` but not `$tree` and not in your expected result.  Can you explain why that is? Is it okay to ignore users if they are not in the tree?

Comment: I started to write an answer for this, but I have realized that you haven't offered a minimal, relevant sample for me to test and demo on.  I am voting to close this one.

Comment: @mickmackusa sorry for that... i have updated the example inputs and results. they should allow u to demo properly